# Issue with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I try add and compile ffmpeg library in my own android application. When I add native support and add ffmpeg library in jni, Eclipse show many errors, something like:

```
uint8_t  *bufferConverted=NULL;
static GLuint textureConverted=0;
```

errors:

```
Type 'uint8_t' could not be resolved
Symbol 'NULL' could not be resolved
Type 'GLuint' could not be resolved
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolve this issue!!)) 
In project **properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and symbols -> Includes** 
and add folowing path:

```
C:\android-ndk\platforms\android-5\arch-arm\usr\include
```

Comment: in my case I needed to use /arch-x86_64/usr/include. I use mac OS 64bits, NULL wasn't resolved either though